# R - number of duplicates for all columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe df and I would like to get the number of duplicates per column. Something in the spirit of:

```
apply(df, 2, max)
apply(df, 2, min)
```

How can I do that?

Here is some data:

```
> head(df)
  var1   var2            var3                 var4               var5                            
1        2018-12-31      9999990021150905     10156671           0             
2        2018-12-31      9999990033012133     13400459           0             
3        2018-12-31      9999990033012171      2152130           0             
4        2018-12-31      9999990019036848     11132102           0             
5        2018-12-31      9999990002922830      4758221           0             
6        2018-12-31      9999990020714416      3236013           0
```

Comment: I added some data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
apply(mtcars[c("vs","am","gear","carb")],2,function(x){
  sum(duplicated(x))
  #length(x)-length(unique(x)) another way
  #sum(is.na(x)) sum of NA's
  #sum(x==1) check how many in column equal to ...
})
  vs   am gear carb 
  30   30   29   26
```

Another way

```
colSums(is.na(mtcars))
```

Comment: Does this give the number of duplicates or the number of unique?

Comment: @adrCoder Duplicates.

Comment: Good. I will accept. How can I count the number of elements that are equal to something e.g. equal to NULL or NA? How can I check that by using your code?

Answer (score 1):

Another way using duplicated :

```r
dfr <- read.table( text= "
             var1   var2            var3                 var4               var5                            
1        2018-12-31      9999990021150905     10156671           0             
2        2018-12-31      9999990033012133     13400459           0             
3        2018-12-31      9999990033012171      2152130           0             
4        2018-12-31      9999990019036848     11132102           0             
5        2018-12-31      9999990002922830      4758221           0             
6        2018-12-31      9999990020714416      3236013           0  ",
           header = TRUE)

apply(dfr, 2, function(x) sum(duplicated(x)))
#> var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 
#>    0    5    5    0    5
```

Or with `purrr` and `dplyr` from the `tidyverse` :

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(dplyr) )
suppressPackageStartupMessages( library(purrr) )

dfr %>% 
    purrr::map_dbl( ~sum(duplicated(.)) )
#> var1 var2 var3 var4 var5 
#>    0    5    0    0    5
```